# Allow Privileged Containers in Kubernetes on Google Container (GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using a Kubernetes cluster deployed through Google Container Engine (GKE) from the Google Cloud Developer's Console, cluster version 0.19.3.  I would like to run a privileged container, like in the [Kubernetes NFS Server](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/nfs) example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
  labels:
    role: nfs-server
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nfs-server
      image: jsafrane/nfs-data
      ports:
        - name: nfs
          containerPort: 2049
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
```

Since the default Google Container Engine configuration does not allow privileged containers, the Kubernetes API imediately returns the following error:

> Error from server: Pod "nfs-server" is invalid: spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: forbidden '<*>(0xc20a027396)true'

How can I allow privileged containers in my Google Container Engine cluster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: Privileged mode is now enabled by default starting with the 1.1 release of Kubernetes which is now available in Google Container Engine.

---

Running privileged containers (including the NFS server in that example) isn't currently possible in Google Container Engine. We are looking at ways to solve this (adding a flag when creating your cluster to allow privileged containers; making privileged containers part of admission control; etc). For now, if you need to run privileged containers you'll need to launch your own cluster using the GCE provider.

Comment: Thanks for the update, hopefully this gets added soon!

Comment: Now that Kubernetes is 1.0, they talk about it in their docs here: http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/examples/nfs/README.html (Just for reference)

Comment: Google Container Engine still doesn't support privileged mode with the 1.0 Kubernetes release. It will support privileged mode once the 1.1 release is out where privileged mode is enabled by default.

Comment: Update: Privileged mode is now enabled by default starting with the 1.1 release of Kubernetes which is now available in Google Container Engine.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/391) talk about that (look at the end).

Comment: That Github Issue addresses the allow_privileged flag for the deploy-it-yourself solution to a Salt provider (gce, aws, vagrant), but not for Google Container Engine (gke), which is a managed Google Cloud Platform service

Comment: He will need the allow_privileged=true to set up a cluster no ? I undestood it in the way you explain "your own cluster using the GCE provider". Am I wrong ?

Comment: The kube-jenkins-imager project go on that way to able privileged (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kube-jenkins-imager/blob/master/cluster_up.sh). It's a gke project. It did run, but the tricks seems to not work for now. (Changes to clusters name maybe ?)

Comment: GKE clusters (https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) are fully managed by Google.  Robert works at Google and confirmed that they are working to expose the allow_privileged option, but it's not available yet.

Comment: I didn't understand because connecting to node, going to config and switching allow_privileged=true did the work on container engine. I did it for a month.

BUT !, it seems that don't work anymore with the v0.19 of k8s. There is an introduction of managed master that break the trick.