# PostgreSQL in Openshift won't execute the entrypoint and can not start the database

Tags: postgresql, docker, openshift, openshift-origin, docker-entrypoint

We have a read-only Postgresql database that should run in Openshift cluster.
We are using RHEL as the undrlying operating system.
Our Dockerfile will install postgres software,  create the database instance, loads the data to it than shuts the database down and save the image.
We are using only bash and sql scripts and deploy the database using flyway.

When starting the container the entrypoint script will simply startup the database instance using `"pg_ctl"` command  then perform an endless loop to keep the container running.

The Dockerfile has as the last command USER 26, where 26 is the id of the postgres user. The entrypoint script can be started as the postgres user or by a `sudo user`.

Everything is working well in Docker.

In Openshift the container is started by a different user belonging to the root group, but not the root user nor the user 26. Actually Openshift ignores the USER 26 clause in the Dockerfile.
The user starting the container (we'll call it containeruser) has anyhow no rights to start the postgres instance , so when running the entrypoint it will get permission denied on the postgresql data folder.
I have tried different options, adding the containeruser user to the wheel group and modify the sudoers file to allow it using sudo and start the entrypoint as postgres user but with no success.
So I have my database image ready but can not start it in Openshift.
On the openshift configuration side we are not allowed to make changes like allowing sudo usage, or starting the container as root or postgres user.

Any idea or help to this problem?
I am not an Openshift expert.

Thank you!

Best regards,
rimetnac

Comment: Have you checked parameters like securityContext or privileged? FYI:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124368/allow-privileged-containers-in-kubernetes-on-google-container-gke
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#grant-access-to-the-privileged-scc

Comment: I will check whether we can run the container as the postgres user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After gathering the comments from all contributors I can asnwer my question as follows:

1. Option 1
   When you create the postgres database during image build, you must configure openshift policies to allow starting your container as the user that created the database during image build. Use this option when the database must be filled with data and this operation takes much time making it inappropriate for a container start. the entrypoint will only start the already prepared database.
2. Option 2
   Create your database when starting the container using the entrypoint script. Use this option when the database creation is fast enough to be done at container start.
3. Option 3
   See the last comment from Adrian which seems to answer all the problems anyhow I didn't got the time to test it.

Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices.

The preferred choice is to fix your image so that it can run as any user. For this, do not use the existing `postgres` user. Create a new user, where that user has group `root`. Then ensure that all directories/files that PostgreSQL needs to write to are owned by that user, but also have group `root` and writable by group. When the container is then started up, it will run as an assigned user ID, not in `/etc/passwd`, and so will fallback to using group `root` still. Because the directories/file are writable to group `root`, everything will still work. For more information see:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

Specifically, section 'Support Arbitrary User IDs'.

The second option if you have admin control of the cluster, and your security team do not object that you are overriding the default security model, is to allow your image to be run as user ID it wants to.

First create a new service account:

```
oc create serviceaccount runasnonroot
```

Next grant that service account the ability to run as non root user ID of its choosing.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user nonroot -z runasnonroot --as system:admin
```

Then patch the deployment config to use that service account.

```
oc patch dc/mydatabase --patch '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccountName": "runasnonroot"}}}}'
```

Note that this still requires you use `USER` in the image with an integer user ID and not `postgres`. Otherwise it can't verify it will run as non root user. That is because if you use a user name instead of user ID, you could be maliciously mapping that to root.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have some other options to try out.
Would it be possible to still use the postgres user having ID 26 which is set in the base image I am importing from ( FROM baseimage) and change its group to root and also modify the rights on the postgres data folder as indicated by you instead of adding a new user? I will try it anyhow.

Comment: Usually you would use a new account, instead of changing the group for the existing user account and going back and fixing the group on all directories/files, but technically it could work. You do have to be careful about changing permissions after the fact in new container layer as it makes new copies of files and so makes image larger.

Comment: I understand, in our case we use a docker baseimage with postgres software and user already installed and can not change this part.
Great help from your side!

Comment: Why not base it on the OpenShift PostgreSQL image, which is already setup with permissions to work in a multitenant environment.

Comment: I tried several alternatives, actually postgres database can be started only by the user owning the data.  I get the error "The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory." when I start the instance with container user having group 0. Maybe I can overrule this one with a parameter.

Comment: The reason you are getting that is because you are pre-creating the database files during the image build. PostgreSQL requires the database files to be owned by the user it runs as, but your files will be owned by a different user. You would need to add your database file to the image as a tar file but don't unpack it. When the image is run, just before PostgreSQL is started, then unpack the tar file with the database files in it to the appropriate location. They way the files are owned by the correct user.

Comment: The only other way to get around it is the other suggestion of running the pod under a service account which allows you to run it as the UNIX user ID the image wants to use.

Comment: I have realised, after doing the last tests, that starting and populating the image with data during image build causes the problems.Our image is quite big, the creation and filling might take even hours,  so we can't afford doing this on the container start but need to be done before. during the build process.Unpacking the tar file upon start might be a solution, but this will also take longer. We will analyse the second option in the meanwhile. I really appreciate your support. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure whether you would be doing anything with the data which changes it, which would be bad for subsequent runs, but you could pre-load the database into a persistent volume rather than the image, and mount the persistent volume into the container. This would be no good though if need multiple deployments using it at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I spent days figuring this out and found one good solution.

OpenShift Origin runs an image as a user created by it, as explained in [this](https://blog.openshift.com/jupyter-on-openshift-part-6-running-as-an-assigned-user-id/) OpenShift blog post. This prevents programs from being able to access needed files and directories. To successfully run a program on OpenShift Origin, the blog post provides two solutions, however, the first will not work for PostgreSQL and the second has two disadvantages (explained in the notes):

1. Grant group write access to the directories used by the main program.

*This will not solve the problem because, although the PostgreSQL files will be accessible by any program, they must be owned by the owner of the PostgreSQL process.*

2. Ensure that when operating system libraries are used to look up a system user, one is returned for the ID of the user OpenShift Origin runs the image as. The following are two methods for doing this:

   1. Use a package called nss_wrapper, "which intercepts any calls which look up details of a user and returns a valid entry."
   2. Make the UNIX password database file (/etc/passwd) have global write permissions in the image build so that the OpenShift user can be added to it in the S2I run script.

*Each option has a disadvantage: 1. install an extra package and 2. make user accounts insecure.*

---

The best solution is to build the docker image to **run as** the user OpenShift Origin will run the image as. I built [this instructional image](https://hub.docker.com/r/adrianbartyczak/openshift-postgresql-10-postgis/) with it.

One additional problem to note is that, as the owner of the PostgreSQL process must be the owner of the files and directories accessed by PostgreSQL, PostgreSQL must be set up (i.e. initdb, roles, databases, etc.) during the image build. This is because file ownership can only be changed during the image build and the ownership of the files must be changed after PostgreSQL has been set up for the reason explained in #2 below.

Here are the complete steps with notes for setting up PostgreSQL in the image build:

1. Manually create the PostgreSQL data directory and change its ownership to a non-root user that will be used to initialze PostgreSQL and set up the components (e.g. roles and databases) required to run the server on OpenShift Origin.

*This is required because the "initdb" executable must be executed by a user other than root and will need access to the data directory. Additionally, this user cannot be the user OpenShift Origin will run the image as because it is not in the system.*

2. Switch to the non-root user.

*This is required because the initdb executable must be executed "as the user that will own the server process, because the server needs to have access to the files and directories that initdb creates" (PostgreSQL documentation) and because the PostgreSQL server will be started to set up components (e.g. roles and databases) required to run the server on OpenShift Origin.*

3. Run the "initdb" executable.
4. Start the PostgreSQL server, set up the required components (roles, databases, etc.) and stop the PostgreSQL server.
5. Switch back to the root user.
6. Change the ownership of the PostgreSQL files and directories to the user OpenShift Origin will run the image as.

---

*Edit (06/20/18): I have found that there is a solution to set up PostgreSQL after the image is built. The user OpenShift Origin will run the image as can be added to the system at the start of the build. This will allow PostgreSQL to be set up and the ownership of its files and directories to be changed after the image build.*